# isomorphisms between tensor products.

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

if we have 3 vector spaces $V_{1} V_{2}$ W such that none are trivial,

If $V_{1} \otimes W \cong V_{2} \otimes W $ does $V_{1} \cong V_{2} $ ?

Comment: If $V_1$ and $V_2$ are finite dimensional of different dimensions and $W$ is not, then no.

Comment: Note that if they're all finite dimensional, taking the dimension of both sides shows that $\dim V_1 = \dim V_2$, which for vector spaces is enough to show they're isomorphic.

Comment: Also false for abelian groups or modules.  With abelian groups, $- \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ kills all torsion so, e.g., tensoring with $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3$ gives the trivial group in both cases, yet the groups are not iso.